# How to use scss @include

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have a SCSS file, and I want to `@include transition(all, 0.5s);` But scss gives

**Error message:**

```
Scss compiler Error: no mixin named transition
```

Here is my `SCSS`:

```
a {
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  @include transition(all, 0.3s);
   &:hover {
     background-color: #444;
     @include transition(all, .5s);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 @mixin reset-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

then to use it

```
@include reset-list
```

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin

But I see that you are trying to use parameters in your mixin

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sass/arguments.htm#:~:text=Explicit%20keyword%20argument%20can%20be,of%20argument%20can%20be%20omitted](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sass/arguments.htm#:%7E:text=Explicit%20keyword%20argument%20can%20be,of%20argument%20can%20be%20omitted).

```scss
@mixin bordered($color, $width: 2px) {
  color: #77C1EF;
  border: $width solid black;
  width: 450px;
}

.style  {
  @include bordered($color:#77C1EF, $width: 2px);
}
```

So in short:
Declare your mixin before including it. Your error says that the mixin does not exist

```scss
@mixin transition($includes, $length) {
  transition: $includes $length;
}

.style  {
  @include transition($includes: all, $length: .2s);
}
```